# Anyway in GORM to preview the schema DDL that will run during migration before running it?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, amazon-aurora

We are using Golang and GORM for ORM and database schema migrations.  Using the defautl AUtoMigrate is nice to add tables/columns/indexes that are net new.  One big issue with Postgres, specifically AWS AUrora Postgres is it seems even a simple alter table add column with no default and no not null constraints still creates a full on AccessExclusiveLock.  This caused us downtime in production for what is otherwise a deployable infrastructure anytime with zero downtime.

Postgres claims this wont cause lock, but think Aurora has some innodb engine magic that does cause one, probably for read replica consistency ?

Regardless, in our deploy shell script trying to see if we can ask GORM to give us the DDL it would run, like a preview, without running it.  Anyway to do that?

Comment: also, anyone know work around to actually avoid the lock in this setup?

Comment: There is a direct way to do this. Also, there is an closed issue https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1920.